# Prove that if $a,b\geq0$ and $a^2<b^2$ then $a<b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

> Prove that if $a,b\geq0$ and $a^2<b^2$ then $a<b$.

How would one prove this?
I know that if $a^2<b^2$ and $a,b\geq0$ then $a^2=b^2-k$, $k\in(0,b^2]$, but I'm not sure about where to go from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $(b+a)(b-a) = b^2 - a^2 > 0$, which means that $b+a$ and $b-a$ have the same sign and neither is zero. Since $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, then $b+a$ is positive, so so is $b-a$ i.e. $b > a$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $b\leq a$.  Then because of the compatibility of multiplication with the total order on $\mathbb{R}$, and because $a,b\geq 0$, we know that $ab\leq a^2$ and $b^2\leq ab$.  Using transitivity, we then find that $b^2\leq a^2$, contrary to hypothesis.  Thus, it must instead that $a<b$.

Answer (score 3):

$$a^2 < b^2 \implies a^2 - b^2 < 0 \implies (a-b)(a+b) < 0$$

$a+b >0$ because they are both not negative so it must be the case that $a-b<0$ and so $a<b$